# Hablitar y deshablilitar todos los TextBox de una pagina

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una página `aspx` donde tengo mas de 200 `TextBox`, es como un Formulario, entonces tiene dos opciones al entrar a la Pagina una de solo "Mostrar" y el otro es "Editar", las opciones se habilitan con dos `CheckBox`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if ((CheckBoxMostrar.Checked == true))
    {
        CheckFalse();
    }
}
```

Evento de `CheckFalse()`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      public void CheckFalse ()  {
            //No es broma son como 200,sólo pongo 6
            Textbox1.Text= false;Textbox2.Text= false;Textbox3.Text= false;
            Textbox4.Text= false;Textbox5.Text= false; Textbox6.Text= false;
      }
}
```

La pregunta es: Cómo Habilitar y deshabiltar todos de un solo tiro? Sin necesidad de poner todo.

Answer (score 4):

Si los textbox estas sobre la Page podrias ayudarte con linq usando

```
public void CheckFalse()  
{
    foreach(var txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        txt.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

con el `OfType<>` puede localizar sobre la coleccion Controls todos los de un tipo concreto

Comment: Solo apuntar, que durante el diseño tambien es interesante jugar con los nombres de los controles, asi por ejemplo si haces textbox de pago imaginate, los puedes llamar txtpago_ y si haces textbox de cobro, los puedes llamar txtcobro_ y luego utilizando la respuesta de @leandro, podrias trabajar especificamente con los textbox que te interese en cada caso.

Answer (score 0):

Un método de ejemplo para habilitar/deshabilitar todos los **WebControls** o los **HtmlGenericControls** a partir de un control padre (puede ser la pagina entera `this.Page` o un control especifico de la pagina y sus controles hijos, un `fieldset`, `div` contenedor, `panel`, etc...)

```
    public static void RecursivoModoControles(Control control, bool enabled)
    {
        // Validar argumentos 
        if (control == null)
           return;

        // ¿Es un WebControl?
        WebControl webControl = control as WebControl;
        if (webControl != null)
            webControl.Enabled = enabled;

        // ¿Es un HtmlControl?  
        HtmlControl htmlControl = control as HtmlControl;
        if (htmlControl != null)
                htmlControl.Disabled = !enabled;

        // Tratar los controles hijos de forma recursiva
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            RecursivoModoControles(child, enabled);
    }
```